# PHP convert JSON array to nested

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to get JSON by name and save it as a variable with everything related to that nest,
what would the best way to accomplish this?
(in my scenario the names are unique)

```
[{
    "name": "Joe",
    "age": "30",
    "gender": "male"
},
{ 
    "name": "Logan", 
    "age": "27",
    "gender": "male"
}]
```

to something like this

```
{
"Joe": [{
    "name": "Joe",
    "age": "30",
    "gender": "male"
}],
"Logan": [{
    "name": "Logan",
    "age": "27",
    "gender": "male"
}]
}
```

i need to be able to search on the name to get the correct one, the API switches order so can't get it from just id

Comment: Hmm, step back a bit and think to yourself is this the correct way to do this? In your wanted output you are now duplicating a field when there's no need to do so. Whos to say that those names will always be unique?

Comment: Are you sure you want the result to be an object containing single-element arrays?

Comment: why do you need/want this, exactly? You already have the name information within the JSON, this just duplicates it. And an array-per-name which, if your names are unique, will only ever have one element in it seems a bit pointless.

Comment: can you paste original json_decode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi This might helps you

```
$list = '[ 
   { 
      "name":"Joe",
      "age":"30",
      "gender":"male"
   },
   {  
      "name":"Logan",
      "age":"27",
      "gender":"male"
   }]';


$newjson = json_decode($list, true);
$final = [];

foreach ($newjson as $key => $value) {
  $final[$value['name']][]=$value;
}
$finaloutput = json_encode($final, true);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($finaloutput);
echo "</pre>";
exit;
```

The output is

```
{"Joe":
[{"name":"Joe","age":"30","gender":"male"}],

"Logan":
[{"name":"Logan","age":"27","gender":"male"}]}
```

Comment: This output does not quite match what the OP asked for. It appears that the new object with named properties should have "collections" (arrays) as those named properties.

Comment: @JAAulde Hi Now the output as expected

Answer (score 1):

The [Laravel Collections Library](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections) is a very useful lib to use cases like yours.

For this problem you could use the [keyBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-keyby) method!

```
$json = '[ 
   { 
      "name":"Joe",
      "age":"30",
      "gender":"male"
   },
   {  
      "name":"Logan",
      "age":"27",
      "gender":"male"
   }
]';

$array = collect(json_decode($json, true))->keyBy('name')->all();

print_r($array); // will be the array with the keys defined by the name!
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-keyby

Comment: Your answer may be correct, but it should include a code-sample that operates on the OP's example data.

Comment: @TonyChiboucas Okay, i've provided a sample code segment.

Comment: Now it makes a strong case for how Laravel Collections can simplify these problems!